# Crash:com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ipad, crash-reports

In a crash report I am seeing multiple thread with com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority. Can someone please let me know what does this means?. I have unable do find any lead to fix the crash.

```
com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority
Thread : com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3873dc7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x387a3dcb _pthread_wqthread + 310
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume this is due to [memory overcommitment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment).

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back that up? Documentation of what this queue is for?